# How to use proxy in project scrapy-splash?

Tags: proxy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying use proxy in scrapy-splash. I found question [using proxy with scrapy-splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646438/using-proxy-with-scrapy-splash)

Then I use like:
 `yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse_page_site, args={'wait': 1.5, 'proxy': 'http://202.74.243.214:31255'})`

But it seems not working. Can anyone point me in the right way?

Comment: Did you got it working?

Comment: Thanks @Gallaecio replied! I had resolved that problem. Because, I used the free proxy, i think it not working well. I'll close my question.